# EXCEL: Set focus on specific cell after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Should be a simple question:

I have the following script which pastes data:

```
Dim a As Range
Set a = Selection
Selection.Cut
Range("C1:I1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Upon pasting, the ActiveSheet moves to the cell in which its pasting in.  How do I re-focus on the cell from which the data was cut?

I want to put the focus on the Range that is currently held in the 'A' variable.

I tried this:

```
a.Select
```

And

```
a.Activate
```

but, it doesn't actually move the activeSheet to the correct area; it just selects it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you seem to want can be accomplished in a single line:

```
Sub OneLiner()
   Selection.Cut Range("C1:I1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

A single space after the **cut** keyword means the destination follows.

There's no need to Dim or Set **a**, as you're not even using **a** as a variable in your code.

Doing it this way does not use the clipboard, change the position of the cursor or page location.

Comment: This is very efficient, but I have a secondary problem edited above which is also moving the focus