# Call SetFocus for a textbox with Excel VBA in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

When I call `SetFocus` for my textbox, it throws this error:

```
Run-time error '438':   
Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

Is `SetFocus` readily available in Excel 2013 or do I have to patch or update any component of my Excel?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507592/excel-set-focus-on-specific-cell-after-pasting

Comment: I want to SetFocus to a textbox not a cell. Thank you.

Comment: How do you call the setfocus? Do you using as a method on the textbox variable?

Comment: please add the relevant part of your script, it might help us to come to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Setfocus()` probably never throw an error like that!!

---

> *Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)*
>
> This method or property does not exist for this OLE automation object. See the object's documentation for more information on the object and to check the spellings of properties and methods.

Here you have a method `SetFocus()`, So you need to know *when this method does not exist*!

---

In Office 2013 if object or one of its containers is not visible or enable, it throw this error:

> *Run-time error '2110':*
> Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

---

And as I tested making loop by raising `Enter Event` is also don't throw error, And also for similar using `SetFocus()` method:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    TextBox2.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

---

And I can't figure any other reason !

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?646411-RESOLVED-How-can-I-make-setfocus-ot-Textbox-in-vba

*You are using Excel after all, but you have the textbox on a worksheet rather than a userform.
Setfocus will work for textboxes on a Userform, but as you have discovered, not if they are on the actual worksheet.
Instead of setfocus try activate:*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
TextBox1.Activate
End Sub
```